# Angular UI not updating when variable updated in Hostlistener

Tags: javascript, angular, events, event-handling

I am using HostListener for capturing the event on window closed from 3rd party payment gateway in my Angular 12 Project. I am updating the variable inside the HostListener event but the UI is not getting updated when I change the flag to true from false.

Here is my code.

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event']) onMessage(event): void  {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      if (event.data.status == "CLOSED") {
        this.showPaymentInfo = true;
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: I think your code is not getting to run when you close window.

Comment: @GRD Code is running. But in the HTML it's not getting updated.